# How to animate a Radial Gradient smoothly outward

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I would like animate a Radial gradient that moves smoothly outward from a center point in waves.

Here are two different storyboards I have tried:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="RadialStoryBoard" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)" From=".1" To=".7" Duration="00:00:03" Storyboard.TargetName="RadialTest"  />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" From=".2" To=".8" Duration="00:00:03" Storyboard.TargetName="RadialTest"  />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Offset)" From=".3" To=".9" Duration="00:00:03" Storyboard.TargetName="RadialTest"  />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Offset)" From=".4" To="1" Duration="00:00:03" Storyboard.TargetName="RadialTest"  />
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="RadialStory2Board" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="RadialTest">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value=".5" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="RadialTest">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value=".7" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="RadialTest">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value=".9" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="RadialTest">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="1.1" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded"> 
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource RadialStory2}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Here's the object:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="RadialTest" Height="50" Width="150" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="4" Margin="5">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5,0.5" RadiusX=".15" RadiusY=".15" GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5"  MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" SpreadMethod="Repeat" >
                        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.2"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.3"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.4"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
```

I've tried several different variations but this is about the closet I've come.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you ***cannot*** take benefit of `SpreadMethod="Repeat"` here to create the circles. Because we have to animate the offsets, but the offsets (in each circle) already fill the range `0-1`. That means animating the offsets will significantly change the radials and make a flickering result. So you have to define multi `GradientStop`s instead of using SpreadMethod of Repeat to create the effect. When creating multi `GradientStop`s, you also have to set the `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` to `1` so that we have more space for the gradient stops. The rule here is the offset of a `Black` (or `Yellow`) should be animated to the offset of ***the next*** `Black`(or `Yellow`) GradientStop. That will fulfill a ***cycle*** and after that the transition is nearly smooth and does not cause any flicker:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="RadialStoryBoard" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="RadialTest">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="0.125" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="RadialTest">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value=".25" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="RadialTest">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value=".375" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[4].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="RadialTest">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value=".5" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[5].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="RadialTest">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value=".625" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[6].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="RadialTest">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value=".75" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[7].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="RadialTest">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value=".875" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

</Storyboard>

<RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5"  MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox">
      <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0"/>
      <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
      <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0"/>
      <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset=".125"/>
      <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset=".25"/>
      <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset=".375"/>
      <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset=".5"/>
      <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset=".625"/>   
</RadialGradientBrush>
```

Note about the removing of `SpreadMethod` and the change in `x:Key` of the `Storyboard` I posted above. Also I think you can just use `DoubleAnimation` (linear) instead of the simple `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` above (of course you may want some complex timing in future with that kind of animation).

Comment: Is there a way to make the rings each circle less "defined" so that they bleed more into each other, or should I accomplish that by using a darker and lighter yellow instead of hard stops of Black and Yellow?

Comment: @jrandomuser not sure what exactly you want it to look. You can try playing with changing the offset colors as well as the ***distance*** between the offsets. I've tried using `#ff888800` instead of `Black` and it looks like there is more smooth transition between the colors. As I said in my answer, the core mechanism here (to solve the problem) is don't rely on the `SpreadMethod=Repeat`, just create multi GradientStops and tweak them to what you want. (as long as we animate the offsets, this is the only way I think).